# Filter for unique values from one column based on duplicate values from another column

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am summarizing response-time data where a unique Case Number has multiple records (consisting of Unit, Status, and Date/Time) for each status update; however, some records have a Unit with a Status of “PAGED” but do not have a corresponding “ARRVD” status for that Unit (usually because the Unit is cancelled but there is no corresponding log entry for a cancellation). I would like to isolate those as unique values, but only for the records of that Case Number.
Like this:

[image: filter for unique values]

I can achieve this manually by selecting only the cells in the Unit column with the same Case Number and then using Conditional Formatting → Highlight Cells Rules → Duplicate Values → "Unique" values with "Light Red Fill with Dark Red Text".

The problem is, I need to do this for 50K+ records/rows, and need a way to search for unique Unit values among the records of a particular Case Number, then move to the next Case Number (again, several records) looking for unique values in the Unit column.

I have a rough idea of the logic for this type of query, but I'm not sure how it translates into an Excel formula. In the sample data (screen capture, above), I've used the Highlight Cells Rules for the entire column; however, it fails to capture cell B12, because that Unit (MA118) also responded to Case Number 16D22 and therefore is calculated as not unique, whereas for Case Number 16D05, that Unit is unique (“PAGED” at 1:08:28 AM but never arrived).

Comment: (1) Are the records (rows) always sorted as you have shown, so that, if both present, the “PAGED” and “ARRVD” entries for a particular Case/Unit combination will always be on consecutive rows?  (2) You say you want to “isolate” the unique (unmatched) entries.  Do you mean highlight them visually, with conditional formatting, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Hi Scott. I just saw this, but yass's answer did what I wanted. Just briefly, however, (1) yes, the STATUS field is filtered to only show PAGED and ARRVD, then a custom sort orders them by CASE NUMBER first, UNIT second, and DATE/TIME STATUS third (oldest to newest date/time), so that if the responding unit was not cancelled, it will always be in consecutive order, PAGED-ARRVD. (2) By isolate, yes, I meant to highlight or otherwise designate the unique values for removal from the table in order to do a simple calculation of ARRVD time minus PAGED time in order to get the actual response time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new Column E, Unique, in E2 write the following:
`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$14&($B$2:$B$14)=A2&B2))=1,"Unique","")`

You can drag it down
A2:A14 Case Number column
B2:B14 Unit column change references to correspond your Data ($A$2:$A$50000 and $B$2:$B$50000)
Keep $ for absolute references
`Sumproduct` will count each A2&B2 value in the whole Data (if not unique it will be >1)
`If` is used to test the result of `Sumproduct`,

- <>1 it will write "" empty
- =1 it will write Unique

When finish you can sort to have the rows with Unique together

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help, yass, and for the super quick response. Clearly it was an easy fix for you, but I wouldn't have figured that out all on my lonesome. Worked perfectly! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the rows are sorted as shown,
a simpler way to check for unique (non-matched) records is

```
=AND(C2="PAGED", OR(A2<>A3,B2<>B3))
```

Simply, for rows where Status is “PAGED”,
it checks whether the next row has a different Case Number or Unit. 
This can be used directly, as-is, with Conditional Formatting,
or (as in [yass’s answer](//superuser.com/q/1198702/150988#1198715))
in a `=IF(condition, string, "")` formula.

I have been able to put this in another column and sort by it,
but I’m not sure whether that’s reliable.